# Camera sensor artifacts next to edges in calibration images; what is causing these?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, camera-calibration

I am trying to image some ChArUco targets using a monochrome machine vision camera with a CMOS sensor and the attached images show the artifact I am observing:

**2-pixel-wide bright vertical streaks adjacent to light-to-dark edges (only on light-dark transitions from left to right)**.

[image: 2-pixel-wide bright vertical streaks adjacent to light-to-dark edges (only on light-dark transitions from left to right)]

Here is another example where the white-to-black edge is nearly vertical, and the contrast is higher.

**The "ghost shadow" of the edge is less perceptible but still there**

[image: The "ghost shadow" of the edge is less perceptible but still there]

Any ideas as to the cause and remedy?

I have tried changing the camera's gain, exposure time, lens aperture etc. But, all these settings do is change image exposure and contrast, which can mask the effect, but not eliminate it (as in the 2nd example image).

I have received some guidance suggesting the streaks may be caused by the over-exposure and saturation of the white regions. I will try and reduce the exposure...

Comment: It’s a 4-pixel-wide pattern. Maybe your sensor has one AD converter per four pixels? The first two pixels converted show less smearing than the other two. But why is it only on the diagonal edges, not the horizontal ones? I still think that it’s caused by overexposure, but I cannot explain exactly what is happening. Do you have more information about the sensor, other than “CMOS with a rolling shutter”?

Comment: @CrisLuengo First, thanks for your help and interest. I agree, overexposure does seem the most likely culprit, but it will be next week before I can work on this again. The sensor is an [On Semi MT9P031](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mt9p031-d.pdf) in a [Basler Pulse puA2500-14um](https://www.baslerweb.com/en/products/cameras/area-scan-cameras/pulse/pua2500-14um/) camera.

Comment: speak to Basler. they sold it to you, they should know what's going on, or have a real interest in solving this for you (and all their other customers)

Comment: oh btw, it could be PWM-dimmed light showing up in the row scan of the camera. your computer display could also be such a light source. shut everything off, use daylight. if the effect is gone then, you'll know it's artificial light. the image looks overexposed already, so if there's more light, it could cause this type of bleeding... per row, whenever the light is on while that row is scanned.

Comment: Since you got the camera used, check through all the settings for anything that's not exactly as it came from the factory.  Someone may have gotten "clever" (note that "clever" and _actually clever_ are two different things) -- if you see a "sharpen (left)" and "sharpen (right)" setting pair and they're markedly different, fix those first!  If it were me I might even call Basler back in the hopes that they'd at least support me to the extent of getting the camera back to as-sold condition.

Comment: @TimWescott - I bought the camera new from a Basler distributor, not Basler themselves... Changing settings back to factory defaults isn't hard and that doesn't help. I think I possibly have a bad unit; might be worth pestering Basler again.

Comment: Do you know if the sensor has any optical lowpass filtering in front of the sensor? My understanding is that these filters acts like a continuous domain 1-dimensional comb filter that can be oriented in any direction, and several can be combined.

Comment: @KnutInge - not that I know of. Since it is a monochrome camera, it does not have the traditional IR filter found on color cameras.

Comment: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mt9p031-d.pdf "Color Filter Array : RGB Bayer Pattern, Column and row skip modes to reduce image size without reducing field−of−view (FOV), Column and Row Binning Modes to Improve Image Quality when Resizing Skipping reduces resolution by using only selected pixels from the FOV in the output image. In skip mode, entire rows and columns of pixels are not sampled, resulting in a lower resolution output image. A skip 2X mode skips one Bayer pair of pixels for every pair output. Skip 3X skips two pairs for each one pair output."

Comment: Still not sure this applies. From [Basler pulse user manual, p11](http://www.altavision.com.br/Arquivos/Basler/Manual/Manual_Pulse_USB.pdf): "Mono or color (color cameras include a Bayer pattern RGB filter on the sensor)." Also, not sure RGB filters, even if present, fit what you described above and how they would lead to the specific issue I am observing.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not a definitive answer, but as close to one as I can get after various tests:

- It is not exposure. Over-exposure/saturation only makes the problem more easily visible. Though hard to see, the artifacts are still present in a not-saturated image.[image: not-saturated image]
- It also isn't room-light flicker. Daylight tests weren't feasible, but I tried exposure times as long as a second (with zero analog gain, and almost fully stopped down aperture). This would average out any flicker/PWM, but the streaks were still present.
- Basler were unhelpful - they would only talk to me if I purchased the camera from them, which I didn't. The re-seller's support staff also leaned towards over-exposure, but I probably led them that way with my question.
- I believe it is my hardware, maybe even the one camera I have. I tried a Basler Ace camera, **which has the same sensor**, and there is no streaking, even in over-exposed images.  [image] This camera has a Gig-E interface as opposed to USB3, but that should be irrelevant.

I had hoped what I was seeing might be a known "edge" case with CMOS sensors, but I guess not! Thanks Cris and Chris for your suggestions.

Comment: I'm working with image sensor chips these days, so I'd be interested to know if an image that goes sharply from white to 50% gray to black shows the stripes on the gray-black transition.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be linked with the camera model. Here, I am using a basler daA2500-14uc with the same image sensor (MT9P031). The edge ringing looks very similar to yours:

[image]

- The ringing occurs only vertically which is why I rule out problems with the lens optics.
- As to my tests, it is not room light flickering.

I reached out to basler and hope to update this post with an answer.

Comment: Sort of glad someone else sees the same issue; perhaps we will have an answer... Good Luck with Basler - they would not help me as I bought the camera from a distributor, not from Basler directly.